# Remove standard objects

Tags: custom-object, standard-objects

I want to remove some objects from my org eg: Product2, Macro and others. The problem is because I cannot find a way to do it, I have deleted custom objects but this ones are different.

Could some one help me?

Comment: You cannot delete standard objects

Comment: Why do you want to do that? If you need to delete those objects you are probably on the wrong SFDC product...

Comment: Seems like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). As mentioned by the other comments, it will be easier to help you if you explain what led you to this desire in the first place.

Answer (score 6):

You can't delete the definitions of standard objects.

If you don't want them to be available to your users under any circumstances, you should remove all object-level permissions ("CRUD") from all of your profiles for those objects. That will prevent your users from creating or interacting with any records in them.

Comment: N.B. You will not be able to modify the permissions for Standard Profiles like "Marketing User" or "System Administrator"